# How can I connect to Postgres with mix command on Phoenix framework?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to run mix ecto.create on Phoenix project and got error:

```
00:30:34.332 [error] GenServer #PID<0.328.0> terminating 
    (RuntimeError) Connect raised a CaseClauseError error. The exception details are hidden, as they may contain sensitive data such as database credentials.
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:40: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:497: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/4
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:353: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:135: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3                                                  
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
(Mix) The database for Discuss.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:
(RuntimeError) Connect raised a CaseClauseError error. The exception details are hidden, as they may contain sensitive data such as database credentials.
        (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:40: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
        (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:497: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/4
        (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:353: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
        (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:135: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
        (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

My config/dev.exs

```
# Configure your database
config :discuss, Discuss.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "elixir",
  password: "Ohtai3ai",
  database: "discuss_dev",
  hostname: "127.0.0.1",
  pool_size: 10
```

My Elixir version is 1.6.6 (compiled with OTP 19)
Postgres 10

Answer (score 2):

Out of date `postgrex` dependency could be the reason, try upgrading it.

```
mix deps.update postgrex
```

The solution comes from [postgrex issue #370](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/issues/370#issuecomment-365861721) which is easily found by [googling the exact error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Connect+raised+a+CaseClauseError+error.+The+exception+details+are+hidden%2C+as+they+may+contain+sensitive+data+such+as+database+credentials.&oq=Connect+raised+a+CaseClauseError+error.+The+exception+details+are+hidden%2C+as+they+may+contain+sensitive+data+such+as+database+credentials).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Just update new versions for 
  phoenix_ecto 3.3.0
  postgrex 0.13.5
  ecto 2.2.10